# ASP.NET GridView - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a gridview, that I made editable. That works... sort of.

Now I'm trying to **update** a row with new data.

The row has columns like:

=========================

| Time | Date | Project | etc etc |

=========================

I'm trying to save the contents of the edit boxes that appear as i **Edit** a row.

The way I do it is like this:

`TextBox time = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTime");`

`--linq-object-reference--.time = Convert.ToInt32(time.Text);`

But I recieve an error... Anyone know why?

**EDIT:**

To clarify my problem... I wanna find out how to fetch the *contents* of those `TextBoxes`, like in this picture:
[image]

**EDIT2:**

Okay, here's the *exact* error...[image]

Comment: how you are showing time in gridview i mean what format(01:30,12:00am/pm,or 1.30) i think the string representation of your time can not be converted to integer.

Comment: The date should not be a problem, but it's shown as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt` eg. a DateTime. But my Time field represents `hours,minutes` spent for a Task/Project, whatever... :)

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: `NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` @ Line: `linqObject.time = Convert.ToDouble(time.Text);`

Comment: @Graham Clark: he is getting object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @ can you clarify at what statement you are getting the error        TextBox time =(TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTime");
   OR
--linq-object-reference--.time = Convert.ToInt32(time.Text);

Comment: try debug the code using breakpoint and check what value are you getting in textbox.text property

Comment: @Devjosh: oh yeah, I didn't see the title!

Comment: @ Updated my question with a snapshot of the exact error message.

Comment: ok now it seems that you are showing comma separated values in the textbox hence it can not be converted to double

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? See my post on how to extract data from data controls http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2008/12/12/getting-your-data-out-of-the-data-controls.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `5,4` or `17-05-2011 14:15:31` is the text in your `txtTime` TextBox, but neither of these are going to be able to be converted to an integer. For the first field, you'll probably need some custom string parsing, and for the second, you should be able to use `Convert.ToDateTime(time.Text)`.

**EDIT:**

Ok, your error message is a bit confusing, as it says the error is in `Convert.ToDouble`, but you've put `Convert.ToInt32` in your question. Anyway, you've got a `NullReferenceException`, so either `linqObject` is null (so you can't access the `time` property), or `time` is null (so you can't access the `Text` property). Maybe some null checks will help you out.

another **EDIT:**

Ok, so your real problem is you can't get a reference to your `txtTime` TextBox. You'll probably need to post some markup for your GridView and some code for the event handler. Here's some suggestions:

- If you debug into your event handler, check the value for `e.RowIndex` - make sure this corresponds to the correct row.
- Ensure the ID string you're using in the code-behind is exactly the same as the ID in the markup.
- Are you using any UpdatePanels, or is the GridView being updated client-side?
- Is ViewState turned off?

Comment: **My problem/question is** _HOW_ do I point to the specific TextBoxes? The data validation / parsing is not a problem at all. But it says it can't find the control named `txtTime`...

Comment: Sorry, was a miscopy on my part... Should be `Convert.ToInt32`

Answer (score 0):

Time should not be saved as integer in database. It is better to save it as DateTime in database.So set your -**-linq-object-reference--.time** as a Datetime type.

Then Use the following code to **convert your textBox string value**(HH:mm ->eg:03:45 ) **to DateTime** using the following code:

```
using System.Globalization;

--linq-object-reference--.time=DateTime.ParseExact(time.Text,"HH:mm",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Hope this will solve the issue...